# OOP PHP: how do i assign a variable value?

Tags: php, oop

Not very good at putting this question into words....

I'm using an API to update some customer information

```
$customer =             new Customer();
$customer->first_name = $value;
$customer->update();
```

The above would update the `first_name`, however I'd like to variable where first name is like:

```
$attribute =                'first_name';    
$customer =                 new Customer();
$customer->$attribute =     $value;
$customer->update();`
```

Which would then reference the public vars in the Customer class.

I want to avoid writing a method(setter) for every attribute.

Comment: have you tried the above? Dit it work? If so, what is the question?

Comment: $customer->{$attribute} = $value;

Comment: Your problem is probably the typo `$attrubute`.

Comment: *(reference)* [Variable variables](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: @Alin typo was just here in SO, now fixed

Comment: I'd say your problem isn't connected with the code you provided. Could you please provide a complete working example or show us `var_dump($customer)`?

Comment: @Haroldo [then you are doing something wrong](http://codepad.org/aLYVOX14)

Comment: @Haroldo See the example I posted in my answer.

Comment: @gordon, thanks. ps. http://codepad.org/ looks useful, surprised I've not come across it before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `$obj->$attr` and `$obj->{$attr}` will work in the same way. The `{}` are redundant in this case. They make sense when you need to write something like `$obj->{"123"}`.

```
<?php
$obj = new stdClass();
$attr = 'my_attr';
$obj->$attr = 'test'; 
var_dump($obj);
?>
```

The problem with your code is that you have a typo. Or if the typo was only in the text of question, then you don't have any problem.

Comment: Cool these both work, in what cases would the braces be appropriate? arrays?

Comment: @Haroldo When there is ambiguity or when the syntax isn't allowed. Ex. `$obj->{$arr[3]}` instead of `$obj->$arr[3]` or `$obj->{"123"}` instead of `$obj->123`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like

```
$attr = 'my_attr';
$obj->{$attr};
```